# How to pop many items from list?

Tags: python, list

I want to pop certain items from my list. This is my code:

```py
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
popVal = [0, 5, 8]
for i in popVal:
    lst.pop(i)
```

The expected output should be `[2,3,4,5,7,8]` as index `0`, `5` and `8` are removed from `lst`

However, I get a error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
IndexError: pop index out of range
```

And if I print my list, this is the output

```py
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]
```

Comment: You're changing the length of the list, so the indexes are _changing_. Even if you didn't hit an error, you wouldn't get the right values out.

Comment: Would work if you start with the higher index numbers first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you pop an element, the list shrinks. As such, what used to be at index 8 for example, is now at index 3.

Assuming your list of `popVal` is strictly ascending, the following modified code would work

```py
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
popVal = [0, 5, 8]
for n, i in enumerate(popVal):
    lst.pop(i - n)
```

This ensures that as the list shrinks, the index to pop from shrinks accordingly as well.

Answer (score 2):

You should iterate through popVal backward and pop the last item first:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
popVal = [0, 5, 8]
for i in popVal[::-1]:
    lst.pop(i)
```